# Toolbar and links customization in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, branding

I have some questions regarding editing:

- How can I remove a link that is the page title?

[image]

- How can I modify the tabs created?
- Also, how can I delete the title over the tabs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**How can I modify the tabs created?**

To modify Site Navigation Settings,

- If your site is team site, Just click on the `Edit links` in the Top Navigation.

[image]

- Else, go to Site Setting > Look and Feel > Navigation > Modify the setting as you prefer (Move Up - Move Down).

[image]

**How can I delete the title over the tabs?**

It's the site Title, Are you sure you need to delete it?!! though if it's your requirement, you can Edit/Remove the Site title as the following:

- Go to Site Settings > Title, Description, and Logo > Remove the Text in Title Field.

[image]

You can also use the below CSS to hide Site Title!

```
<style>

#DeltaPlaceHolderPageSiteName
{
     display:none !important;
}

</style>
```

**How can I remove a link that is the page title?**

Check this [How to Remove Home Page Title URL to be unclickable in Teamsite SharePoint 2013?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/09/22/remove-page-title-url-in-team-site-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I cant find the >Title, Description & Logo

Comment: I want to also delete that link/title

Comment: Are you sure you can't find Title, Description & Logo?

Comment: For some reason I cant find it, I dont have that option available.

Comment: All I see is:  Look and Feel (Design Manager, Master Page, Welcome Page, Device Channels, Change the look, import Design Package, Navigation, Image Renditions; Site Administration (Site libraries and lists, Term store management, Content and structure); Web Designer Galleries (Site Columns, Site content types, Web parts, master pages and page layouts, Themes, Solutions, Composed looks); Search (Result Sources, Result types and Query Rules)